# Mac stops responding from time to time

Tags: mac, google-chrome, crash

I started using Mac yesterday, since then it stopped responding a lot. Each time it happened I restarted the system but it happens again. I also got "he's dead, Jim" error many times on Chrome.

Is there anyway to get rid of this issue?

---

Installed memory(RAM) : 4.00 GB (3.87 GB usable)

Comment: Can you be more precise? What were you doing when it stopped responding?

Comment: @LoïcWolff: I had Skype and Chrome opened. What else should I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it happens consistently, remove one of the sticks of RAM and use the computer normally, then use the other one alone and use the computer normally.  Usually you'll find that one stick is exhibiting the problem, and not both, if it's a hardware problem.  Replace the bad stick.

Make sure you haven't disabled virtual memory.

Have you installed any drivers, for instance for USB, display, or networking devices?  Try uninstalling them.

If it doesn't appear to be a RAM stick problem, or a driver issue, the next troubleshooting step is to backup your system, then reinstall OS X fresh.  Install only those applications you absolutely need, then use it for awhile.  If it continues to exhibit the problem, take it to apple for hardware problems.  If the problem goes away, then add your applications and data as you need it, keep track of what you're adding, and if the problem starts happening again then suspect the items you most recently added as the cause.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1270364), "He's dead, Jim" message appears

> if the operating system has terminated the tab’s process due to a lack of memory

So it seems to be a RAM problem.

If your Mac is still under warranty, take it to an Apple Store to get it look at.

Comment: Thank you. I read that page before posting the question and didn't help.

Comment: I think in this case, the "he's dead, jim" message is an internal error to the chrome browser for @gigli and not a system error for Chrome OS where chrome is taking the place of Mac OS. I'll see if I can find a better link to how to debug browser rendering errors in Chrome for Mac OS but my guess is the chrome browser is temporarily monopolizing the free RAM/CPU of your mac and possibly crashing so the mac pauses to collect why the app crashes before moving on to the next task.

Comment: Yeah, there was no doubt about that (it's Chrome on OS X and not Chrome OS). What I was saying is : it's a RAM problem, Chrome does not have enough to show the page. So either Chrome is taking to much (for some reason) or one of the RAM stick is bad.

Answer (score 0):

"He's dead, Jim" error is usually thrown by Chrome when the system goes out of memory. The first things you should check are:

- Is your RAM ok? Does the system see all RAM amount correctly? You could use [Rember](http://www.kelleycomputing.net/rember/) to test your memory for faults.
- Did you recently install new software or updates which might be using a lot of memory?
- Did you install any plugin/extension for Chrome which might be using an excessive amount of memory?
- Did you change your using/browsing habits? Ie: how many windows/tabs are you opening and what's their content? Flash websites/games/movies might be eating a lot of your available memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, The problem is more that Mac stops responding than "he's dead, Jim".

Comment: @Gigili - first two points apply for all system. See my updated about testing your RAM!

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this sounds like a memory problem. Why not try opening Activity Monitor (you can find it in /Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app) and checking which applications are the memory hogs to begin with.

Set the dropdown list at the top of the window to "All Processes". You can then order the list of processes by the "Real Mem" column, or click the "System Memory" tab at the bottom of the window to see current memory status. This will at least give you an idea of the problem applications using the most memory.